# How to translate whole website by google transltion?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-translate

This is my code :

```
<div id="wrap">
 ⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯  
 ⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯⋯
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("language", "1");
  google.setOnLoadCallback(submitChange); 
  var wrap_text = '';
  function submitChange(){
   wrap_text = document.getElementById('wrap').innerHTML;          
   google.language.translate(wrap_text, 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW', function(result) {  
    var resultBody = document.getElementById('wrap');  
    alert(result.translation);    
    if (result.translation){
     resultBody.innerHTML = result.translation;
   }      
    else { 
    resultBody.innerHTML = wrap_text； 

    }
   });
   return false;
  }      

</script>
```

it does not work, if I replace wrap_text to some words, it works.

who can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a good solution http://translate.google.com/translate_tools?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to escape it to work, at least that's what they did in the example code:

```
var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
```

See: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html